# JBoss 7: issues logging from a custom login module

Tags: java, logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm working on a custom login module, and have been unable to get it to log. Currently, I have it deployed as a module in $JBOSS_HOME/modules.  I have the login module referenced in standalone-full.xml (which is used to perform the server startup), and have added a logger category to standalone-full.xml for the login module's package, set to TRACE.  When I start the application server, and attempt to hit the server, I get the following message in the logs:

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger ()

All of the documentation that I've been able to find relates to logging within an ear or war, which doesn't apply to this situation. If at all possible, I don't really want to define my own logging configuration, I'd like to use the server's logging configuration (I'm upgrading from JBoss 5.x, which just defined a single logging configuration for everything).

Thanks in advance!
Rob

Comment: Can you specify which version of JBoss AS 7? In EAP 6.x and WildFly logging has changed quite a bit.

Comment: Could you show your module.xml ?